# notepad ++ how to take some words line

Tags: notepad++

**please help me,,**




**BEFORE**

TY  - JOUR
T1  - IJGO at the FIGO 2015 Congress
JO  - International Journal of Gynecology & Obstetrics
VL  - 131
IS  - 1
SP  - 1
EP  - 2
PY  - 2015/10//
T2  -
AU  - Adanu, Richard M.
SN  - 0020-7292
DO  - blablabladx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ijgo.2015.07.002
UR  - blablabla/science/article/pii/S002072921500483X
ER  -

TY  - JOUR
T1  - FIGO consensus guidelines on intrapartum fetal monitoring: Introduction
JO  - International Journal of Gynecology & Obstetrics
VL  - 131
IS  - 1
SP  - 3
EP  - 4
PY  - 2015/10//
T2  -
AU  - Ayres-de-Campos, Diogo
AU  - Arulkumaran, Sabaratnam
SN  - 0020-7292
DO  - blablabladx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ijgo.2015.06.017
UR  - blablabla/science/article/pii/S0020729215003926
ER  -


**AFTER**

IJGO at the FIGO 2015 Congress
FIGO consensus guidelines on intrapartum fetal monitoring: Introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a three step appoach:

1. Remove everything in a line that does not start with T1: use Replace

   - Find what: ^(?!T1).*$
   - Replace with: (leave empty)
   - Select  Regular expression
   - Replace All
2. Edit -> Line Operation -> Remove Empty Lines
3. Replace "T1 - " with nothing